# Journey Builder - Wait By Attribute issue where some contacts breezed through when they should have waited

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a birthday journey that contains a Wait By Attribute canvas element. The idea is that **contacts enter the journey 30 days before their birthday**, go through a random split where some get the first of two emails straight away, and the others wait until 7 days before their birthday to get the first email.

For the later, I have a Wait By Attribute configured as below:
[image]

[image]

The contacts that enter the journey have their birthday 30 days from now. So **today (18th Feb) 88 contacts entered and I triple-checked their birthdates and all have a birthdate of 20th March**, which is correct. However, you can see below that of the 50 contacts that landed on the "Wait until 7 days before birthdate", 39 have already progressed through and received the first email. These contacts should have waited until 13th March before progressing.

[image]

So given the above configuration of the Wait By Duration, what is going on?

The only thing I can think of is that the Wait By attribute also account for the year, which would mean it thinks the birthdates are in the past and therefore progressed them straight through? However, this doesn't explain why some contacts are still waiting, given that every contact does have a year value in their birthdate.

Any idea what's going on?

(Also note I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here, so apologies in advance if that's the case!)

Comment: Since we cannot see the Birthday you entered in your dataextension. How does the birthday look alike? Has the user birthday on the 20th March 1970 this date is long gone and the following statement becomes true: "If the calculated date is in the past, contacts proceed to the next activity". Or did you really insert the 20th March 2021? Normally you would kind of design it otherwise with SQL automations or trigger based stuff (from my experience)

Comment: Yes the birthday is a Date field in the data extension and is like 20th March 1970. So as you say, it is in the past and the contacts proceed (this I think is where I had misunderstood the functionality of the Wait By Attribute). However, it doesn't explain why some contacts did still wait even though their birthdate is in the past?

Comment: Did they really wait or did they just enter the activity and instantly went to the next activity?

Comment: Some waited and some went straight through. That is what's weird about it. And that seemed to be totally random since everyone has a birthdate in the past (obviously!).

I have since added a field for NextBirthdate and set this using the SQL query as you suggested and it works well now. So I think that is the way to use this feature.